# How do I use string parameters in a MYSQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, string, stored-procedures

I am currently trying to write a MYSQL stored procedure which allows me to call two product codes and return rows from a table that match the given product codes.

Whever I run the following code, it returns a table, but this table seems to ignore the given parameters.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getprofit;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getprofit (IN c1 char(10), IN c2 char(10))
BEGIN

    SELECT p.productName, o.productCode,
    p.buyPrice, o.priceEach, (priceEach - buyPrice) AS profit
    FROM products p, orderdetails o 
    WHERE (p.productCode = c1) OR (p.productCode = c2)
    AND p.productCode = o.productCode
    LIMIT 5;

END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL getprofit('S18_1889', 'S18_1984');
```

Answer (score 0):

AND is higher precedence than OR; you are doing:

```
(p.productCode = c1)
OR
(p.productCode = c2) AND p.productCode = o.productCode
```

when you likely mean:

```
( (p.productCode = c1) OR (p.productCode = c2) )
AND
p.productCode = o.productCode
```

So add parentheses around the OR condition.